# Typescript difference between typeof class and class as property type

Tags: typescript

I have `index.d.ts`,

Initially, I assign a class `ApplePaySession` to `Window`, for me to be able to use `window.ApplePaySession`. However, when trying to access static methods, typescript complaints.

```
// index.d.ts
interface Window {
  ApplePaySession: ApplePaySession | undefined
}

// MyCode.ts
const isAvailable = (): boolean => {
  const ApplePay = window.ApplePaySession
  return Boolean(ApplePay) && ApplePay.canMakePayments()
}

// ApplePaySession definition
    /**
     * Indicates whether the device supports Apple Pay.
     * @returns true if the device supports making payments with Apple Pay; otherwise, false.
     */
    static canMakePayments(): boolean;

// Error
Property 'canMakePayments' does not exist on type 'ApplePaySession'. Did you mean to access the static member 'ApplePaySession.canMakePayments' instead?ts(2576)
```

I have to change my definition in `index.d.ts` to this in order for it to work:

```
interface Window {
  ApplePaySession: typeof ApplePaySession | undefined
}
```

Why is that? what's the difference between assigning class type using `typeof Class` and `Class` in typescript?

Comment: sorry actually my code is in `.ts`, it was a typo that i did just now. I only declare `index.d.ts` to add properties to `window` @Dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given following ...

```
interface Window {
  ApplePaySession: ApplePaySession | undefined
}

class ApplePaySession {
  constructor() {}
  static canMakePayments() {
    return false;
  }
}

const isAvailable = (): boolean => {
  const ApplePay = window.ApplePaySession   // <-- This will be treated as an instance and not as a type
  return ApplePay && ApplePay.canMakePayments() || false // <-- Error, Being a static member, canMakePayments will have to be accessed via type ApplePaySession, like ApplePaySession.canMakePayments()
  // return ApplePay && ApplePaySession.canMakePayments() || false  //<-- Ok, access via type not instance
}
```

It complains because we are accessing an instance member via an interface property, and which means it needs to be a `value`(an `object` created from class `ApplePlaySession`). However since`canMakePayments` is a ***static*** member, it will have to be accessed via a `type` and not via instances of `values`.

Now... what will you adjust, depends upon your use case.

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after couple of hours scratching my head yesterday that was my assumption as well. However you have a mistake, if it's already an instance then we cannot reinitiate it, thus I can't do `new ApplePaySession()`. Only if it's `typeof ApplePaySession` then I can initiate it because it is merely a type. I have tested that.

Please change your answer so I can accept it. thanks!

Comment: Well... I kept that assignment only to `showcase` what can and cannot be assigned to that field, when the type of the the filed is actually a `class` and when it's a `typeof class`... I do not intend you do the same. Let me try to reword that...

Comment: @RobertTirta, have edited my answer and removed the confusing part...